# Unable to resolve "./components/victory-primitives/rect" from "node_modules\victory-native\lib\index.js"

Tags: react-native, expo, victory-charts, victory-native

[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module ./components/victory-primitives/rect from C:\Users\TheLu\repos\DashboardExpence\node_modules\victory-native\lib\index.js:

Do I need to be able to use victory native in expo in some way?